# Eliminar una columna si no se agrego otra en php con sentencias preparadas

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statements

tengo una duda, espero que me la puedan solucionar.
Primero que nada, tengo que aclarar, que el código que hice me funciona correctamente, pero no del todo. Les explico primero que es lo que quiero hacer.

Estoy practicando con PHP y MYSQLI, y estoy creando como modo de practica un sistema de usuarios y notificaciones.
Bien, el formulario de registro funciona correctamente, la primera notificación se agrega correctamente, pero mientras yo armaba el código me pasó algo.
Sucedía que yo, cuando me registraba con este sistema, se creaba correctamente el usuario, pero no la notificación, y no es la idea, porque la idea es que si alguno de los dos querys no funcionaba, que directamente no haga nada, que no me genere el usuario ni la notificación.

Intente con:

```
if(true && true){}
```

Pero no funcionaba, y no se que es lo que pasa. Dejo todo el código que obviamente se puede mejorar un montón, pero como les dije, estoy recién empezando y yo necesito una guía, no criticas. Se que mi código se puede mejorar totalmente, y agradecería que en vez de criticar mi código, me ayuden. Gracias de antemano a aquellas personas que sugieren que haga X cosa antes de criticar.

Código:

```
include "../class/class.conexion.php";
include "define.urls.php";

$db = new Conexion();

if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
    $name = $_POST["name"]; // Nombre real del usuario
    $username = $_POST["username"]; // Nombre de usuario o nickname
    $email = $_POST["email"]; // Email del usuario
    $password = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Contraseña del usuario

    $imagen_de_perfil = website_images."/profile-image-lyrians.png"; // Imagen de perfil por defecto
    $imagen_de_portada = website_images."/profile-cover-lyrians.png";
    $rango = "novato"; // Rango inicial del usuario
    $descripcion = NULL;
    $confirmacion = "no confirmado";

    // Notification
    $id_notification = NULL;
    $notificacion = htmlentities("http://unapagina.com;Gracias por formar parte de esta comunidad;Te recomiendo leer este post");
    $time = time(); // Tiempo exacto de la notificacion
    $idAdmin = 1;

    // Verifico si en la tabla users no hay ningun usuario con el mismo EMAIL o USERNAME
    if ($verify = $db->prepare("SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?")) {
        $verify->bind_param("ss", $username, $email);
        $verify->execute();
        $verify->store_result();
        $verify->bind_result($username, $email);

        if ($verify->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "0";

            $verify->close();
        } else{
            $user = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_image, 
                                                     user_cover_page,
                                                     username,
                                                     user_description,
                                                     email, 
                                                     password, 
                                                     name, 
                                                     rango,
                                                     email_confirmation,
                                                     user_register_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

            $notification = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO notifications (notification_user, 
                                                                     notification_send_user, 
                                                                     notification_title, 
                                                                     notification_datetime) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

            $user->bind_param("sssssssssi", $imagen_de_perfil,
                                            $imagen_de_portada,
                                            $username, 
                                            $descripcion, 
                                            $email, 
                                            $password, 
                                            $name, 
                                            $rango,
                                            $confirmacion,
                                            $time);

            if ($user->execute()) {
                $userID = $user->insert_id;
                $notification->bind_param("iisi", $userID, $idAdmin, $notificacion, $time);

                if ($notification->execute()) {
                    echo "1";
                } else{
                    echo "notification";
                }

                $user->close();
                $notification->close();
            }
        }
    } else{
        echo $db->error;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo único anómalo que veo en el código, por el momento, es que en el binding, indicas que `notification_datetime` es del tipo numérico `i`, todo lo demás parece correcto. Ten en cuenta que si las inserciones violan una regla de integridad, como por ejemplo, crean llaves duplicadas, las mismas no se realizan... creo que es bueno controlar eso, recogiendo los errores que pueda levantar la ejecución del statement. Algo que te ayudará a determinar el fallo con más exactitud es revisar el log de errores de tu PHP.

Comment: ¿No esta bien, por qué? La variable $time es tipo entero, no esta bien si lo pongo así?

Comment: Si es entero sí está bien. Viendo el nombre pensé que era del tipo `DATETIME`, en cuyo caso debería ser una `s`